# In Flutter with just_audio streaming, audio repeats first set of streaming data numerous times before playing everything else perfectly

Tags: flutter, websocket, just-audio

My code :

```
audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) {
      if(event.processingState == ProcessingState.ready){
        audioPlayer.play();
      }
      if(event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed){
        audioPlayer.dispose();
      }
    });


    final bosMessage = {
      "text": " ",
      "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": true},
      "xi_api_key":
          apiKey, 
    };

    socketChannel.sink.add(jsonEncode(bosMessage));
    socketChannel.stream.listen((message) async {
      final response = jsonDecode(message);
      if (response['audio'] != null) {
        try {
          final audioChunk = response['audio'] as String;
          final uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(audioChunk));
          streamController.add(uint8List);

          await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(myCustomSource);

        } catch (e) {
          print("Error setting audio source and playing: $e");
        }
      }
    });
```

And my MyCustomSource :

```
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final Stream<List<int>> byteStream;
  final List<int> bytes = [];
  MyCustomSource(this.byteStream) {
    byteStream.listen((data) {

      bytes.addAll(data);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that audioPlayer plays the first message thats comng from websocket numerous times. Exactly as many times as the time message comes in. before playing everything else smoothly

I am sure I shouldn't really be doing

> await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(myCustomSource);
> everytime a new stream/message comes in but I am not sure how to just setAudioSource only once.